# What am I doing wrong so confused?

Tags: compiler-errors, basic

I am making a program in BASIC and I know its really bad and I can fix a lot of things but all I was wondering is why I am getting errors for ending subs?

```
' simple calculator
declare sub main
declare sub add
declare sub subtract 
declare sub multiply 
declare sub divide
declare sub question 
declare sub sendBack     'asks to send user back to main menu

main 

sub main     'Where the user makes there selection
dim choice as integer
input "Welcome, would you like to 1.Add 2.Subtract 3.Multiply 4.Divide" ; choice
if choice = 1 then 
    add
elseif choice = 2 then 
    subtract 
elseif choice = 3 then
    multiply
elseif choice = 4 then 
    divide 
else 
    print "Error 404 your choice does not exist, please enter a corresponding number!"
    main
end sub

sub question    'Get 2 integers from user 
dim num1 as integer 
dim num2 as integer 

input "Please enter your first number" ; num1 
input "Please enter your second number" ; num 2 
end sub

sub add     
question 
print num1 + num2 
end sub

sub subtract 
question 
print num1 - num2
end sub

sub multiply 

question 

print num1 * num2

end sub 

sub divide
question 
print num1 / num2
end sub

sub sendBack
dim answer 
input "Would you like to make another calculation, 1.Yes, 2.No" ; answer
if input = 1 then 
    main 
elseif input = 2 
    sleep 
else 
    print "Please enter a valid choice, thankyou!"
    sleep
end sub
```

## Errors I got

```
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(30) error 32: Expected 'END IF', found 'end' in 'end sub'
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(34) error 60: Illegal inside functions, found 'sub' in 'sub question    'Get 2 integers from user'
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(46) error 60: Illegal inside functions, found 'sub' in 'sub add'
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(55) error 60: Illegal inside functions, found 'sub' in 'sub subtract'
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(64) error 60: Illegal inside functions, found 'sub' in 'sub multiply'
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(73) error 60: Illegal inside functions, found 'sub' in 'sub divide'
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(82) error 60: Illegal inside functions, found 'sub' in 'sub sendBack'
C:\Users\Harjit\Documents\Coding (Basic)\calculator.bas(96) error 32: Expected 'END IF' in 'end sub'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing your if statements.

```
IF-
ELSEIF
ELSE
END IF
```

Close your IF statements before closing your subs.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult reading your code; you might want to indent it properly before pasting in the future. :)

Anyway, your problem is with your syntax. After each ELSE statement and its corresponding code, you need to put an END IF.

See http://www.picaxe.com/BASIC-Commands/Program-Flow-Control/if/ for a better understanding of this.

Comment: Oh sorry about the inconvenience I've only used this website once before kinda new and thanks so much

Comment: No problem. Just thought I'd throw it out there for next time. :)